# Consulta SQL Con campo con nombre con punto "Campo."

Tags: sql-server, sql, datatable

Resulta que estoy trabajando con el motor Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
extrayendo datos de archivos .XLSX , y haciendo consultas a determinadas Columnas o campos

[image: Archivo Excel]

Necesito dar formato deseado al Campo "Fecha Movim.", ya se como hacerlo.

El problema es con el nombre de este campo ya que termina en punto "." y no se reconoce el campo adecuadamente.

Adjunto la consulta que necesito hacer y la que e intentado sin [exito.

```
$BSQL_Query = "Select FORMAT([Fecha Movim.], 'dd/mm/yyyy'),[Fecha Valor],Hora,Descripcion,Documento,Debito,Credito FROM [ATLAS$] Where  Debito <> 0 "  ;Consulta dando formato al primer campo
```

```
$BSQL_Query = "Select ['Fecha Movim.'] FROM [ATLAS$] " ;Consulta simple
```

```
$BSQL_Query = "Select [Fecha Movim.] FROM [ATLAS$] " ;Consulta simple
```

Estos son intentos.

¿Hay alguna Forma de realizar exitosamente la Consulta,  Sin cambiar el nombre del campo?

Comment: `$BSQL_Query = "Select [Fecha Movim.] FROM [ATLAS$] "` sin las comillas simples

Comment: no funciona , tambien lo e intentado de esta forma ,

Comment: Habría que ver que mensaje de error producen las consultas y partir de allí. Solo decir que no funciona, o que "da error", no es de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Reemplazar el punto por # y funciona

```
$BSQL_Query = "Select [Fecha Movim#] FROM [ATLAS$] "
```